# How to make contributions to JUNIT open source

Tags: java, junit

How can one make contributions to JUnit or any other open source java framework in general? I am a entry level programmer and any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Start answering questions on the JUnit mailing list. Submit patches for existing issues. What @yi_H said.

Comment: Do you have any concrete contributions in mind? (for Junit)

Comment: I'd also wager to guess that most projects will be much more eager to accept submissions of documentation from unknown contributors over code. (And will likely have a wiki that lets you make these submissions with just registration.)

Comment: Excellent point @Sii. With 99.982% of OSS, the documentation is far behind the actual code. Keep in mind I might have made that number up just now. Anyway, it's a common problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, the method depends on the project. Many have a page detailing how you can get involved. Keep in mind that a level of trust needs to be built up -- don't expect your first submissions to make it in right away, if at all. Don't let that discourage you, though. Getting involved with an open source project is an excellent way to build your own knowledge experience, and helps others at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

JUnit is [hosted at github](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/), like many other projects. So you can clone the source, make a change, commit it, push it to your own fork on github, and then issue a pull request to ask them to merge your changes into the official repo. See the [list of issues](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/issues) for ideas of what types of changes to make.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [www.junit.org](http://www.junit.org) and join its [mailing list](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/junit/).

To see what JUnit project is going on, what new features people expect, which is bugfixes...you could create a topic to discuss in the mailing list.

Hope it will help you!